# Is there a way to copy the text from a List<WebElement> into an other List(string)

Tags: python, arrays, selenium

I manage to get a list of webElements with their xpath and my end goal is to search paste each one of them (1 at the time) in the Google search bar.

My idea was to copy the List(webElements) to another List so that I can store those (string) values and 1 at the time search for them.

The code look like this:

```
nome = wd.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li')
elements=[]
for i in range(0,40):
     nome[i].text=elements[i]
wd.get('https://google.com')
#accepts cookies wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]/div').click()
for i in range(0,40):
wd.get('https://google.com')
wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/input').send_keys(elements[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elements=[elem.text for elem in none]
```

Is what you are trying to do. Go through each element in none and grab the .text.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the *text* from the [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) into another *list* you can use [*List Interpolation*](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/list+interpolation+conditional+python) as follows:

```
nome_texts = [my_elem.text for my_elem in wd.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li')]
```

Comment: @Brodomo Any feedback?